# How can I start using Material UI icons in my REACT project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui

I went through the documentation and found that a bit confusing with the terms like "MaterialIcon, SVGIcons, Icons".
[Here it is](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/)

Can any one give a simple understanding of the process, like from installation to using inside a REACT component?

I prefer using Fontawesome (free version). But this time I needed to use Google and Facebook icons inside my projects which were not available in the free version.
So I had to explore the alternatives.

//I have tried by the followings:
npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react

//Imported Material UI icons
import GoogleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Google';

//Inside component
{GoogleIcon }

//But It doesn't work

Comment: They are components, so `<GoogleIcon />` etc.

Answer (score 0):

MaterialUI requires a theme to be setup for its icons to work properly: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/

Here is a code example:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider  } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GoogleIcon />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Solved my issue by these steps: 

--Run
1. npm -f install @material-ui/core
2. npm -f install @material-ui/icons

--Inside Login.js
import GoogleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Google';

--Inside login component:
<GoogleIcon  onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}></GoogleIcon>

--Dont know if it was a good solution but. It worked for me.